Hurdle Poisson Post Estimation - Partial Effects
I have run a Poisson Hurdle model and I'm using the following syntax for the partial effects for the Zero and the Count part of the model. I'm using the effects package at the moment which may not be compatible with pscl package. I've installed the marginaleffects package as well, but I'm not sure what the right function is for that package.
library(pscl)
library(effects)
data(quine, package = "MASS")

PoissonHurdle_model <- hurdle(Days ~  Eth + Sex + Age + Lrn, 
    data = quine, dist = "poisson")

partial_effects_zero <- allEffects(PoissonHurdle_model,component = "zero")

partial_effects_count <- allEffects(PoissonHurdle_model,component = "count")

I'm getting an error message:

Error in mod.matrix %*% scoef : non-conformable arguments

How do I resolve this? Or what would be the right function for calculating effects using the marginaleffects package? I understand that I could use the margins package but it is not available for the R version that I'm using.

I get an error about "invalid dependent variable" when trying to run your code. Please make sure your example is fully working and reproducible.

I believe these are the commands you are looking for:
library(pscl)
library(marginaleffects)
data(quine, package = "MASS")
PoissonHurdle_model <- hurdle(
        Days ~ Eth + Sex + Age + Lrn,
        data = quine, dist = "poisson")

Average Partial Effects for the Zero component
avg_slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "zero")
#;-) 
#;-)  Term            Contrast  Estimate Std. Error        z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 %  97.5 %
#;-)   Age mean(F1) - mean(F0)  0.000448     0.0607  0.00739   0.9941 0.0 -0.1185  0.1194
#;-)   Age mean(F2) - mean(F0)  0.016649     0.0558  0.29852   0.7653 0.4 -0.0927  0.1260
#;-)   Age mean(F3) - mean(F0) -0.003643     0.0665 -0.05479   0.9563 0.1 -0.1340  0.1267
#;-)   Eth mean(N) - mean(A)   -0.088072     0.0372 -2.36965   0.0178 5.8 -0.1609 -0.0152
#;-)   Lrn mean(SL) - mean(AL) -0.011934     0.0485 -0.24601   0.8057 0.3 -0.1070  0.0831
#;-)   Sex mean(M) - mean(F)   -0.055396     0.0418 -1.32555   0.1850 2.4 -0.1373  0.0265
#;-) 
#;-) Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#;-) Type:  zero

Average Partial Effects for the Response component
avg_slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "response")
#;-) 
#;-)  Term            Contrast Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#;-)   Age mean(F1) - mean(F0)    -4.08      1.193 -3.42   <0.001 10.6  -6.416  -1.74
#;-)   Age mean(F2) - mean(F0)     4.45      1.341  3.32   <0.001 10.1   1.822   7.08
#;-)   Age mean(F3) - mean(F0)     8.08      1.811  4.46   <0.001 16.9   4.534  11.63
#;-)   Eth mean(N) - mean(A)      -8.73      0.901 -9.69   <0.001 71.3 -10.500  -6.97
#;-)   Lrn mean(SL) - mean(AL)     5.67      1.244  4.56   <0.001 17.5   3.230   8.11
#;-)   Sex mean(M) - mean(F)       2.32      0.957  2.42   0.0153  6.0   0.445   4.20
#;-) 
#;-) Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#;-) Type:  response

Partial Effects, holding all covariates to Mean or Mode
slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "zero", newdata = "mean")
#;-) 
#;-)  Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error       z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#;-)   Age  F1 - F0  0.00104     0.0599  0.0174    0.986 0.0 -0.1163 0.1184
#;-)   Age  F2 - F0  0.01613     0.0551  0.2927    0.770 0.4 -0.0919 0.1242
#;-)   Age  F3 - F0 -0.00365     0.0654 -0.0559    0.955 0.1 -0.1318 0.1245
#;-)   Eth  N - A   -0.05161     0.0506 -1.0203    0.308 1.7 -0.1508 0.0475
#;-)   Lrn  SL - AL -0.01408     0.0520 -0.2710    0.786 0.3 -0.1159 0.0878
#;-)   Sex  M - F   -0.09043     0.0906 -0.9976    0.318 1.7 -0.2681 0.0872
#;-) 
#;-) Columns: rowid, term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted, Eth, Sex, Age, Lrn, Days 
#;-) Type:  zero

Partial Effects, holding all covariates to Mean or Mode
slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "response", newdata = "mean")
#;-) 
#;-)  Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#;-)   Age  F1 - F0   -2.506      0.780 -3.214  0.00131  9.6 -4.03 -0.978
#;-)   Age  F2 - F0    2.758      0.880  3.134  0.00172  9.2  1.03  4.482
#;-)   Age  F3 - F0    4.972      1.117  4.452  < 0.001 16.8  2.78  7.160
#;-)   Eth  N - A     -4.255      0.556 -7.657  < 0.001 45.6 -5.34 -3.166
#;-)   Lrn  SL - AL    2.594      0.601  4.317  < 0.001 16.0  1.42  3.772
#;-)   Sex  M - F      0.612      0.858  0.713  0.47578  1.1 -1.07  2.295
#;-) 
#;-) Columns: rowid, term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted, Eth, Sex, Age, Lrn, Days 
#;-) Type:  response


Happy to help! You can check the answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem to avoid a bunch of people looking at it for nothing.

Cheers. Just a quick one. Does "response" mean the same thing as "count". I get different results when I use either.

You should be able to find info about the scale in the documentation of your model-fitting package (here: pscl). It should correspond to the type argument of the predict() function for that package.
